# Scheduling weekly repeatable local notification with fire date from date picker in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, local, repeat

So I'm currently building a schedule app and I'm trying to create a local notification to fire on specific time on specific day of the week, every week. So the first thing I do is get the date value of the start time of the event, then I subtract 5 minutes from the start time value and then schedule the notification. Previously it was very easy just had to type:
`notification.repeatInterval = CalendarUnit.WeekOfYear` but now the command is deprecated in Swift 3 and yeah, so the only way I found is:

```
 let someMinutesEarlier = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: -5, to: startTimePicker.date)

        let contentOfNotification = UNMutableNotificationContent()

        let interval = someMinutesEarlier?.timeIntervalSinceNow

        contentOfNotification.title = "Event starting"
        contentOfNotification.body = "Some notes"
        contentOfNotification.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval: interval!, repeats: true)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: notificationIdentifier, content: contentOfNotification, trigger: trigger)

        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.add(request) { (error) in
            print(error as Any)
        }
```

but this only schedules the notification only once (no matter that the repeat boolean is set to true), because of the year in the someMinutesEarlier...or it's may be something else? Any idea?

Comment: Why don't you use an UNCalendarNotificationTrigger ?

Comment: Are you targeting versions earlier than ios10 or ios10 only?  If you want your app to run on versions earlier than 10 as well, I would probably stick with the deprecated approach for the moment. Otherwise you will need to write both versions and use `available`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As McNight mentionned, you can use `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` like so:

```
let interval = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 - 300 // One week minus 5 minutes.
let alarmTime = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: interval, to: Date())!
let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday, .hour, .minute], from: alarmTime)
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: true)
```

(I haven't tested this code, but this should get you on the right path).

More information [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/uncalendarnotificationtrigger).

**Edit:** Fixed time interval calculation suggested by SwiftyCruz.

**Edit 2:** Updated to use a Calendar to perform the time shift as suggested by RickiG.

Comment: I think Added time should be 60 * ( 60 * 24 * 7 - 5) or 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 - 300

Comment: Thank you! Yes of course UICalendarNotificationTrigger... so simple but needed help. Thank you all and also thank you Paulw11 I would consider this, but mainly I use the new Swift 3 because of the notification identifiers.

Comment: As long as you are happy with ios10 only this is the best approach.

Comment: Shouldn't you be adding an increment to a date component in the calendar, instead of calculating the seconds "offset" from today. Like this : Calendar.current.date(byAdding: Calendar.Component, value: In, to: Date) - if you do the above at a time where a leap year, leap second or so falls, it will be off.

Answer (score 0):

**// Swift2.3**

```
func setLNotification(weekDay:Int , hour:Int, min:Int, second:Int, alertBody:String, type:String, isRepeate:Bool){

    let calender = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
    let dateComp: NSDateComponents?

    dateComp = calender?.components([.Year,.WeekOfMonth,.Month], fromDate: NSDate())
    dateComp?.hour = hour
    dateComp?.minute = min
    dateComp?.second = 00
    dateComp?.weekday = weekDay
    dateComp!.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()

    print(calender?.dateFromComponents(dateComp!))


    let SetCustomDate = calender?.dateFromComponents(dateComp!)

    print(SetCustomDate)

    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    if isRepeate == true{

        switch type {
        case "Weekly":

            notification.fireDate = SetCustomDate!.dateByAddingTimeInterval(60*60*24*7)
            notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Weekday

        case "2 Weekly":

            notification.fireDate = SetCustomDate!.dateByAddingTimeInterval(60*60*24*14)
            notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Day
        case "Monthly":
            notification.fireDate = SetCustomDate!.dateByAddingTimeInterval(60*60*24*28)
            notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Day

        default:
            break;
        }

        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
        notification.repeatCalendar = calender
    }
    notification.alertTitle = "STATS"
    notification.alertBody = "Please update your Stats detail"
    notification.userInfo = ["uid":"reminder"]

    print(notification)

   UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)



}
```